# Post nuclear war comic

Tags: story-identification, comics, post-apocalyptic, nuclear-weapons

There was a comic that told the story of a society based in Iceland. The one story line featured an oil tanker stranded in a desert that a military force was extracting oil from. The militay force was from a militaristic group that the Iceland based society was resisting. I recall there were 2 brothers, one belonged to the Icelandic society and the other was the head of the fascist society. At the end, it was revealed that their father had escaped to an orbiting space station.

Trying to recall the name of the comic or the story itself. I am thinkng mid 80's when I read this but could be an earlier time when it was written.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks: Given neither has an answer, let alone an accepted one, and the only common details between the two are that they're comics involving life after a nuclear bomb, why are you sure they're duplicates?

Comment: @SeanDuggan: Same user, within minutes of each other, similar question, copy and pasted. Even the same misspelling typo in the last sentence. Thought is that he asked the first, and then remembered details, but being a new user didn't know how to edit, and simply asked a new question.

Comment: Ah. I didn't see it was the same user.

Comment: I get that it's the same user, similar title and the last sentence is copy & pasted, but... the description is CLEARLY not of the same comic. There is no similarity between both descriptions, other than "post nuclear". If there is a close reason, "duplicate" ain't one.

Comment: Actually there are 2 separate comics that I was I looking for in the 2 related comics.